# Nested Sorted Group w/ Counts

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out how to take a list and get a group list that each contains groupings with total amounts. I was able to get the first goup done, and looked around on doing nested groups w/ LINQ, however not sure how to get it to work with the information I need. Bellow is a sample list and the coding I have currently.

Sample List

```
var list = new[] {
    new { Product = "Product1", Category = "Category1", Issue = "Issue1" },
    new { Product = "Product1", Category = "Category1", Issue = "Issue2" },
    new { Product = "Product2", Category = "Category2", Issue = "Issue1" },
    new { Product = "Product3", Category = "Category1", Issue = "Issue2" },
    new { Product = "Product2", Category = "Category2", Issue = "Issue1" },
    new { Product = "Product1", Category = "Category1", Issue = "Issue" },
}.ToList()
```

Sample Code

```
var topIssues = from issue in storage.Issues
                group issue by new {issue.Category, issue.Issue} into issueGroup
                let count = issueGroup.Count()
                orderby count descending
                select new { Issue = issueGroup.Key, Count = count};
```

I am doing a group defined by both Category and Issue, then I need the count of items in each group and the list sorted in descending order by this. However, I would like to have a group within these for the Product that contains also contains the count of items for each product also in descending order. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Comment: Can you show expected output??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var topIssues = (from issue in list
                group issue by new {issue.Category, issue.Issue}
                into issueGroup
                select new
                {
                    Issue = issueGroup.Key, 
                    Count = issueGroup.Count(),
                    GP = (from i in issueGroup group i by i.Product into gp select new
                    {
                        Product = gp.Key, Count = gp.Count()
                    }).OrderByDescending(g=>g.Count)
                }).OrderByDescending(d=>d.Count);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes more sense now that I am looking at your example.